# CoreData with multiple databases

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm building an app that is going to rely on 3 separate .sqlite databases.  What methods in my App Delegate am I going to have to edit to allow for this?  Right now, my `managedObjectContext` and `managedObjectModel` haven't been touched from how the template created them.  My `persistantStoreCoordinator` looks like this:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURLConfigA = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbA.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeURLConfigB = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbB.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeURLConfigC = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbC.sqlite"];

//    // Pre-load .sqlite db in Project Navigator into app on first run after deleting app
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURLConfigA path]])
    // dbA
    {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dbA" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSError* err = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURLConfigA error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error preloading database A - %@",error.description);
        }
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURLConfigB path]])
    // dbB
    {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dbB" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSError* err = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURLConfigB error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error preloading database B - %@",error.description);
        }
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURLConfigC path]])
    // dbC
    {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dbC" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSError* err = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURLConfigC error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error preloading database C - %@",error.description);
        }
    }

//    // Put the Configs into the PersistantStoreCoordinator and tie them to their database file
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}};
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"Config_A" URL:storeURLConfigA options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting up dbA - %@",error.description);
        abort();
    }
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"Config_B" URL:storeURLConfigB options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting up dbB - %@",error.description);
        abort();
    }
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"Config_C" URL:storeURLConfigC options:options error:&error])
    {    
        NSLog(@"Error setting up dbC - %@",error.description);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Then, I have a single .xcdatamodelID in my `mainBundle` that has all of my tables/Entities in it, for all three databases.  I used XCode's CoreData editor interface to add Configurations `Config_A`, `Config_B`, and `Config_C`, in addition to the `Default` Configuration.  I've moved the Entities into the Configurations for the databases I want them to be in (each Entity should only be in one database).

I run the app and everything runs fine, and I can read and write data without any problem.  The problem comes when I view the tables (through the terminal or Firefox's SQLite Manager, for example).  All 3 of the databases contain all of the tables, but the tables only have data in the database they are supposed to exist in (there are 0 rows in that table in the other two databases).

Why are all of the tables in each database?  How can I get each database to only include the couple tables I want them to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with what Patrick Goley had in his answer, but I still couldn't get the behavior I was looking for.  After reading what he had, I got the idea to just go and break my three databases into totally separate pieces everywhere I could think of doing so, and that seems to be working.  If someone needs me to post my whole app delegate I will, but the gist of it is:

- I have properties for 3 `NSManagedObjectContext`s, 3 `NSManagedObjectModel`s, and 3 `NSPersistantStoreCoordinator`s.
- I copied the factory methods to create each (which were originally written when I created my app from a template) and hardcoded each to use the appropriate contexts/models/store coordinators.
- I have 3 `NSSet`s that holds the table names for it's respective database, and when I want to read from (or save to) a table, I pass the name of that table, and use the `NSSet`s to get the appropriate context/model/store coordinator.

After spending a lot of time reading all the Apple docs and other threads I could find, I feel like it wasn't supposed to be this difficult to support separate databases, but this was the only thing that's actually doing what I want so far.  I don't know what I was missing before, but this is working, so it will do for now.  If I get more free time in the future I might look into it more and try to figure out the right way, and if I find it I'll update.

Comment: I have implemented multiple core data stacks with only 1 NSManagedObjectModel and it has worked fine. I don't know how that solved your problem but you must've been allowing the data to get saved to the wrong store or merged to the wrong context. models don't control where data goes.

Answer (score 2):

You have added all 3 of your databases (NSPersistentStores) to the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. Therefore, when you perform a save on a Managed Object Context, the store coordinator distributes those changes to all of its stores. Instead, create a persistent store coordinator for each database, perhaps keeping them in an NSDictionary, with a key @"A" for the A database persistent store coordinator, key @"B" for the B database coordinator, etc. Then when you create a new managed object context, you will have to determine which database (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) it belongs to. This will allow you to keep your tables/changes separated and prevent all data going into all 3 databases.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to see this all makes sense to someone =).  When you say at the end of your response "you will have to determine which database (the managed object context) belongs to" - is there an easy way to automatically do this?  Or will I have to know somehow when I create the context?  In other words, are there any methods I can call to find out which `Configuration` or `NSPersistantStoreCoordinator` a `ManagedObjectContext` belongs to?  Or do I just need to hardcode it (so if I set up an "Employees" `Entity` in Config_A, I just need to always call `managedObjectContextA` for that one)

Comment: you could create a method that asks for a context for a given database, something like managedObjectContextForStoreIdentifier:@"A". This method would get the store coordinator for A and create a context from it, in which you will be able to access data from database A. Then use this method passing in either A, B, C as parameters depending on which database you are wishing to access.

Comment: Okay gotcha, that's actually what I did since posting my last comment, good to see I took the right road.  Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: So with this setup, will I still be ok only having 1 .xcdatamodeld in my app, or do I need 3, one for each database?  I tried it with just one, and I'm still getting all the tables in each database.

Comment: are your NSManagedContexts merging in changes from other context's saves with the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification? If they are, make sure that the saving context has the persistent store coordinator before allowing the changes to be merged in to the receiving context

Comment: Hm, I didn't do anything with the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, so I guess it's just using it's default behavior.  I'm just saving my data with `[managedObjectContext save:&error];`.  I have 3 `managedObjectContext`s, and I have it set up to select the correct one based on the table I want to save (I now pass the name of the table I want to save as a `NSString` whenever I save from a view controller or something).  I went ahead and broke it all out into 3 different `.xcdatamodeld`s, and I'm finally getting the behavior I want.